# Choosing the Gauge in Randall–Sundrum model

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge

Given the $5D$ conformally flat metric in Randall–Sundrum model

$ds^2=e^{-2A(y)}\eta_{MN}dx^Mdx^N$, where $x^5=y$

The Einstein tensor is given by

$G_{MN}=\frac{1}{2M^3}(\Lambda g_{MN}+T_{\mu\nu}\delta^\mu_M\delta^\nu_N\delta(y))$,

where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the matter content on the brane localized at $y=0$ and $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant in the bulk.

Setting $g_{MN}=e^{-2A}\tilde{g}_{MN}$, the Einstein tensor reads

$G_{MN}(g_{MN})=\tilde{G}_{MN}(\tilde{g}_{MN})+3[\tilde{\nabla}_M{A}\tilde{\nabla}_N{A}+\tilde{\nabla}_M\tilde{\nabla}_N{A}-\tilde{g}_{MN}(\tilde{\nabla}_R\tilde{\nabla}^R{A}-\tilde{\nabla}_RA\tilde{\nabla}^R{A})]$

Working in linearized gravity, the perturbed metric has the form

$g_{MN}=e^{-2A}(\eta_{MN}+{h}_{MN})$

Taking into account the Christoffel symbols
contained inside the covariant derivatives, the formula gives
$G_{MN}(g_{MN})=\tilde{G}_{MN}(\tilde{g}_{MN})+3[{\partial}_M{A}{\partial}_N{A}+{\partial}_M{\partial}_N{A}-\Gamma^R_{MN}{\partial}_RA-\tilde{g}_{MN}({\partial}_R\partial^RA-\Gamma^R_{RS}{\partial}^SA-{\partial}_RA{\partial}^R{A})]$

Note that, to linear order, the Christoffel symbols are

$\Gamma^R_{MN}=\frac{1}{2}({\partial}_Mh^R_N+{\partial}_Nh^R_M-{\partial}^Rh_{MN})$

Focusing on the {${\mu\nu}$} components, we have

$G_{\mu\nu}(g_{\mu\nu})=\tilde{G}_{\mu\nu}(\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu})+3[-\Gamma^y_{\mu\nu}{\partial}_yA-\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}({\partial}_y\partial^yA-\Gamma^R_{Ry}{\partial}^yA-{\partial}_yA{\partial}^y{A})]$

For $h^y_\mu=0$, the above relation can be recast into

$G_{\mu\nu}(g_{\mu\nu})=\tilde{G}_{\mu\nu}(\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu})+3[-\frac{\partial^y h_{\mu\nu}}{2}{\partial}_yA-\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}({\partial}_y\partial^yA-\frac{\partial_y h^R_R}{2}{\partial}^yA-{\partial}_yA{\partial}^y{A})]$

If there is no matter content on the brane, i.e. $T_{\mu\nu}=0$, we can choose the transverse and traceless gauge

$\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}=0$ and $h^R_R=0$

But if $T_{\mu\nu}\neq0$ how can we choose our gauge in such a way that the conservation condition $\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0$ holds?

Note that $\partial^\mu\tilde{G}_{\mu\nu}=0$, but what about the remaining terms?